# What does "percentage of top nation" mean

Tags: meaning

I've seen [somewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations#/media/File:Jewry.PNG) on the Internet the expression *population shown as percentage of top nation* and I simply can't see what is mean by that.

I can make a few guesses but none of them seem to be confirmed by the map's contents.

Comment: s/b "percentage of *the* top nation". The "top nation" here is Israel. So each countries' Jewish population is given as a percentage of Israel's. The usage in general will depend on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values measured for each nation are shown as a proportion of the largest value measured. Israel has the largest Jewish population, so it gets a green dot representing 100%. France has about 10% as many Jews as Israel—about half a million—so it gets a yellow dot representing 10%. Russia has about 4% as many Jews as Israel, so it gets four red dots each representing 1%

Comment: Actually, it's USA that had the largest number of Jews in the world (about a million more then Israel). But that doesn't affect the quality of your reply. +1 for examples.

Comment: @KonradViltersten- Actually according to the legend on the map in your link it's Israel at 5,313,800.  The map also has the ***the*** as user3169 has pointed out.,